# R how to find how many users only have one value

Tags: sql, r, dataframe

I have a dataframe called user_role where there is a key value (userid). I want to see how many of these user ids only have one value for a categorical variable called role.

Here's some sample data:

```
userid role  
ame1   programmer
ame1   programmer
ame1   analyst
cal5   programmer
cal5   programmer
up2    sales
```

I would like cal5 to be in the output dataset because there was only one role but ame1 should not be in the output data frame since it had more than one role value.

I've tried something like this:

```
("select userid, role, count(*) from user_role  group by userid, role having count(*) == 1")
```

but only get users with 1 row or role value.

```
("select userid, role, count(*) from user_role  group by userid, role having count(*) > 1")
```

doesn't get me only those with one role value even though they have multiple rows

I want to have both cal5 and up2 show up in the output. Ideally, I would like to be able to have a clause where I only include users with 2 or more rows.

Thanks

Comment: Your last comment confuses me.  Originally I thought you just wanted `count(distinct role)`, but then you mention 2 or more rows which would exclude `up2` correct?

Comment: Yes, it would be great if I could specify a minimum number of rows a person would have to have to be included in the output data frame. Does this help? But they would still have to only have 1 value across those minimum of two rows.

Comment: `table(unique(df1)$userid)` will give you the number of unique `role`s per user `userid`. Or using `data.table` you could add conditions `library(data.table); setDT(df1)[, if(uniqueN(role) == 1 & .N > 1) .SD, by = userid]`

Comment: Or `library(dplyr) ; df1 %>% group_by(userid) %>% filter(n_distinct(role) == 1 &  n() > 1)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I deleted my post and didn't find your solution in the comments.  People are busy and may not read each and every comment.

Comment: @DavidArenburg That is also incorrect, I was offline for more than 12 hours yesterday.

Comment: @akrun Ok, this is unrelated to this post, you should just fix your solution rather deleting it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `count` with `distinct` to limit the results to only those users with a single role.  Then to check for multiple rows, use `count(*) > 1`:

```
select userid, min(role) as role
from user_role  
group by userid
having count(*) > 1 and count(distinct role) = 1
```

Comment: It is wrong answer - up2   should be in result too. Just remove "count(*) > 1" from having part and should work

Comment: @Filip this was one of OPs requirements actually

Comment: @DavidArenburg please read once more. "have one value for a categorical variable called role". up2 have one role

Comment: @Filip you haven't read till the end, haven't you. You also haven't looked into the comments

Comment: @Filip -- I specifically asked the OP about this in the comments under the post... The wording of the question is confusing.

Comment: up2 should appear as it only has one role. however, I would like the flexibility to control how many minimum number of rows they need to qualify to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dplyr` package in R

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(userid) %>% summarise(n_distinct(role))
```

Output would look like this:

```
1   ame1                2
2   cal5                1
3    up2                1
```

And you can select based on the condition you want.

Say, all those that are equal to 1.

```
df %>% group_by(userid) %>% summarise(n_distinct(role)==1)
```

Comment: `n_distinct` huh, that's pretty neat and specific

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess `n_distinct` is there for years now. And this solution isn't giving the desired output. I've posted in comments both a dplyr and data.table solution that does

Comment: @DavidArenburg You're free to post a separate answer. I think OP has got what is required.

Comment: There is no point to post two almost identical dplyr answers, rather you should fix yours to match desired output. That's all